# Adding a list of values to SVN:externals via command line

Tags: svn

I am trying to create an automated script that will create a tag and then update the svn:externals property for me automatically. At the moment I am having issue trying to set the full list. I can set an single property by using

```
svn propset svn:externals "external1 http://svn/repos/tags/external1" .\tag_name
```

The issue is if you run that multiple times (we have 10 or so externals on the tag) then it will only set the last instance. I tried a few ways to set this with a list but had no luck

`svn propset svn:externals "external1 http://svn/repos/tags/external1" .\tag_name "external2 http://svn/repos/tags/external2" .\tag_name`

`svn propset svn:externals "external1 http://svn/repos/tags/external1 external2 http://svn/repos/tags/external2" .\tag_name`

`svn propset svn:externals "external1 http://svn/repos/tags/external1,external2 http://svn/repos/tags/external2" .\tag_name`

I also tried looking at svn propedit but I didn't have any luck there. If anyone has done this before your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can define all of your externals in a single file, then set the property with `svn propset svn:externals -f YOURFILE .\tag_name` The contents of YOURFILE should look like this:

```
external1 http://svn/repos/tags/external1
external2 http://svn/repos/tags/external2
```

Comment: @MikeMcLennan if this resolved your issue, please consider [marking the the answer as Accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).